# Is there a limit of records in the IN clause of a query written in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

The question is about DAX query using IN clause

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-in-operator-in-dax/

Comment: How many values do you want to add?

Answer (score 1):

The number of values may not restricted, however it will place limits on you adding and removing items in the measure, or making it performance heavy as it will do an 'OR' in the query engine, and taking a long tine to calculate. If the list is static, I would recommend wrapping the values in a second table, and using that as a look up. Then using VALUES to return the distinct list of items. This lookup can be added to a measure for example:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('TableOne'), FILTER('TableOne', 'Table'[Product] IN VALUES('Table Two'[SomeLookupColumn])))
```